# when do i know i am overfitting a model?

Tags: model, overfitting

This example comes from the documentation of Matlab. Suppose you have data points

```
t      y  
___    ____

  0    0.82
0.3    0.72
0.8    0.63
1.1     0.6
1.6    0.55
2.3     0.5
```

You want to find coefficients $c_1,c_2$ such that $y=c_1 + c_2\exp(-t)$. Least squares will give you $y= 0.4760 + 0.3413\exp(-t)$. The assumption here is that your model comes in the form of $y$.

I tried performing the same set of operations assuming that $y=c_1 + c_2\exp(-t) + c_3\exp(t)$. The results show that $c_1$, $c_2$ changed, but $c_3 \approx 0$. This is all well and good.

So I tried adding more terms, $y = \cdots + c_4f(t) + c_5g(t) + \cdots$.

My questions are: 
1. How do you know you are overfitting a model? 
2. Is there is a way to check which $f(t), g(t)$, etc contributes 'significantly' to the model?

Comment: You are overfitting when your training error is 'low' but test error is relatively 'high'. What is low and what is high is dependent on context.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to balance underfitting/overfitting is to look at bias and variance, simultaneously (see [bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff)).

The variance, which is defined by the variance of $y - \hat{y}$, becomes high when your data is overfit. 
To check "how low" the variance can get without underfitting, you can use the bias, which is $mean(\hat{y}) - y$.